# neo4j graph text search with gremlin

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

How can i make a text search in neo4j with gremlin? I want to search for all the node types and all node properties. I read the gremlin documentation but was unable to find an answer to my problem.

I'm using the API with node and express.

```
g.V.filter{it.*=="a*"}
```

Do i need to install another system to make the text search for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For speed, do filter{it.getProperty('gender').matches...}

For full text search not using a linear scan of vertices, make sure you create a full text index on gender. See Blueprints docs on Neo4jGraph for more information.

Comment: With "full text index" do you mean a neo4j index with key 'gender'? Can you give a link to the part of the documentation you have in mind.

Comment: See the last section at the bottom of: https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Neo4j-Implementation ... This has a code snippet to create a full-text index over a property.

Comment: is there any documentation with sample queries for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
g.V.filter{it.gender.matches('mal.*')}
```

Comment: This results in the following error message: `No such property: gender for class: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.traverser.B_O_Traverser`